# How to get the third last user_id in a specific result set from WordPress database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In the table bellow, the category **Apple** has three rows. What I'm trying to do is picking all user_id within **Apple** category, then get the third last user_id for that category.

Based in the sample data below, the record I want is that where `user_id` is 2. Because there are two more users after that in the same category.

```
id  user_id  category
1   2        apple
2   4        banana
3   6        apple
4   7        berry
5   8        apple
```

My code is failing. When I try to dump the contents of `$sql` variable, with `var_dump`, I get `NULL` all the time.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$post_id = 180;
$category = apple; // the most popular word
$sql = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT e.user_id, COUNT(e.user_id) as count FROM (SELECT user_id, id FROM $table_name WHERE post_id=%d AND category=%s )e WHERE id < e.id",
    $post_id,
    $category
));
foreach ($sql as $value) {
    $user_id = $value->user_id;
    $count = $value->count;
    if ($count >= 2) {
        echo $user_id;     
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: When running that query, do you get any results or just an empty array?

Comment: It's weird because in according to WP docs for `$wpdb->get_results`, "_if no matching rows are found, or if there is a database error, the return value will be an empty array_". What do you get when you do `var_dump($sql);`?

Comment: Oh, sorry actually it doesn't give me anything, using var_dump(), it gave me  null

Comment: `null` means that it got an error when tried to execute your query. You can run your query directly on the database using a MySQL client or PHPMyAdmin, whatever you have, and check which error is that one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your query. The constraint `WHERE id < e.id` will match no rows because you're comparing `e.id` with `e.id` since you have only one (temporary) table in your `FROM` clause. This way `2` will never be less than `2`, for instance.

To achieve what you want, it's needed to count all records with an `user_id` greater than the current one, and then get that records with a count equal to 2. You can do that with the following query:

```
select
    a.user_id,
    count(b.user_id) as count
from 
    $table a 
left join 
    $table b -- join with the same table
on 
    a.category = b.category 
on 
    a.post_id = b.post_id 
and 
    a.user_id < b.user_id -- matching only results where user_id are greater
where 
    a.category = %s 
and 
    a.post_id = %d
group by 
    a.user_id having count = 2; -- exactly 2 rows
```

You can use the query above with your PHP code.